# Dataset with maximal rows by userId indicated

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, max

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID date        var1 var2 var3
AB 22/03/2020  0     1   3 
AB 29/03/2020  0     3   3 
CD 22/03/2020  0     1   1
```

And I would like to have a new dataset that, if it is a maximal column (can happen ties too) leaves the same number of the original dataset on the rows; otherwise set -1 if it is not the maximal. So it would be:

```
ID date        var1   var2    var3
AB 22/03/2020  -1     -1        3 
AB 29/03/2020  -1      3        3 
CD 22/03/2020  -1      1        1
```

But I am not managing at all how to do this. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select only numeric columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df1 = df.select_dtypes(np.number)
```

Or select all columns without first two by positions by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 2:]
```

Or select columns with `var` label by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
df1 = df1.filter(like='var')
```

And then set new values by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with `max`:

```
df[df1.columns] = df1.where(df1.eq(df1.max(1), axis=0), -1)
print (df)
   ID        date  var1  var2  var3
0  AB  22/03/2020    -1    -1     3
1  AB  29/03/2020    -1     3     3
2  CD  22/03/2020    -1     1     1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer! I got a warning and I was trying to fix but I couldn't. I read about the error and I understood, I am just not managing how to fix it. The error is:  

"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

Comment: @Catarina Nogueira How working add copy, if some filtration? Like `df1 = df.select_dtypes(np.number).copy()` ?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use `where` and date `back`

```
s=df.loc[:,'var1':]
df.update(s.where(s.eq(s.max(1),axis=0),-1))
df
   ID        date  var1  var2  var3
0  AB  22/03/2020    -1    -1     3
1  AB  29/03/2020    -1     3     3
2  CD  22/03/2020    -1     1     1
```